# Energy of dipole using the electrostatic energy of all of space

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole

I was watching my online lecs, and we were considering the electrostatic energy of a dipole. First, doing the torque-in-uniform-field calculations, and derived that $U_{rot}= - \vec{p} \cdot \vec{E}$. Standard stuff, until we got to the non-uniform case, where the Prof stated that $U_{total}= - \vec{p} \cdot \vec{E}, F = \left( \vec{p} \cdot \nabla \right) \vec{E}$, and gave it as homework that this matched up with the $p \frac{\partial E}{\partial x} \widehat{x}$ stuff we did in school.

I solved the homework, but it felt a bit unsatisfactory. Also a bit hand-wavy since the 2-charge approximation technically has higher order moments too, so I thought simply knowing the field of a dipole, we may calculate the energy of the dipole. 
Below are some images of the calculations I sent to my TA after I got stuck.

[image: the first part]

[image: and the second]

Observe that the first term simplifies as

[image]

Given that we actually know what the answer is, the second term should got to 0, but I have no idea how it does.

Comment: If you pick a concrete coordinate system for your "spherical limit" step (say, $\vec{p} = p_z \hat{z}$ and $\vec{E} = E_z \hat{z} + E_x \hat{x}$), it's not too hard to show that that integral evaluates to $- \frac{1}{3} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{p}$.  This implies that (a) the integral that you're asking about does not vanish, and (b) there is some error elsewhere in your derivation (though I admit I can't spot it just now.)